# C# string array orderBy problem with accent characters

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq

I wrote a little code where declare a string array and i try to order it with and without stringCompare, but the result always same.

With StringComparer where i use cultureInfo:

```
var strings = new string[] { "asd", "ásd", "álm", "alm" };
var ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hu");
var comp = StringComparer.Create(ci, false);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", strings.OrderBy(item => item, comp)));
```

Without StringComparer:

```
var strings = new string[] { "asd", "ásd", "álm", "alm" };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", strings.OrderBy(item => item)));
```

Both result is:

```
alm, álm, asd, ásd
```

But the correct result will be:

```
alm, asd, álm, ásd
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: I don't know hungarian, but it seems that there are different collations in use. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_alphabet) says that a and á are co-sorted: "While the characters with diacritical marks are considered separate letters, vowels that differ only in length are treated the same when ordering words. Therefore, for example, the pairs O/Ó and Ö/Ő are not distinguished in ordering, but Ö follows O. ". OTOH, SQL Server has more than 100 collations for hungarian.

Comment: You can answer your own question instead of adding the solution to your answer.

Comment: Thank you your rightful remark. I modified it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i found the solution. If i set global CurrentCulture to "hu" or "hu-HU" then words not display in the correct order, BUT i found an extra Culture to Hungarian: "hu-HU_technl".

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/windows/win32/intl/sort-order-identifiers?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Code:

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hu-HU_technl");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
var strings = new string[] { "brummm", "asd", "ásd", "álm", "alm" };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", strings.OrderBy(item => item)));
```

Result: alm, asd, álm, ásd, brummm

You can also reach this with StringComparer:

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hu-HU_technl");
var comp = System.StringComparer.Create(ci, false);
var strings = new string[] { "brummm", "asd", "ásd", "álm", "alm" };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", strings.OrderBy(item => item, comp)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `Ordinal` string comparison

```cs
var strings = new[] { "asd", "ásd", "álm", "alm" };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", strings.OrderBy(item => item, StringComparer.Ordinal)));
```

It gives you

> alm, asd, álm, ásd

Comment: This reproduces the example given by the OP, but I still am not sure what exactly Péter meant by "correct result": some of the different lexical sortings or indeed ordinal sorting.

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, as you wrote. Ordinal compare does not solve my problem. 
Hungarian ABC looks like this: a-á-b-c..... 

Ordinal comparer generate this from strings: alm, asd, álm, ásd. But if i add a new string example: "bab", then result will be: alm, asd, bab, álm, ásd

Comment: Found the solution. Updated my question. Thanks your help guys